# How to connect KnexJS with database Oracle?

Tags: node.js, oracle, knex.js

I have connection but i do not know if it exists in connection the key **odbc**... but even if i throw it away the error informed below persists

```
const knex = require('knex');

// connection database
const dbmdlog = knex({
  client: 'oracle',
  connection: {
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'root',
    database: 'mydb',
    odbc: 'MYDB'
  }
});

module.exports = dbmdlogp;
```

I'm doing a select simple in a collun
But always return error:

```
  Unhandled rejection TypeError: _this2.driver.connect is not a function
        at /var/www/html/myapp/node_modules/knex/lib/dialects/oracle/index.js:143:21
        at Promise._execute (/var/www/html/myapp/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/debuggability.js:299:9)
        at Promise._resolveFromExecutor (/var/www/html/myapp/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:481:18)
        at new Promise (/var/www/html/myapp/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:77:14)
        at Client_Oracle.acquireRawConnection (/var/www/html/myapp/node_modules/knex/lib/dialects/oracle/index.js:142:12)
        at Object.create (/var/www/html/myapp/node_modules/knex/lib/client.js:231:16)
        at Pool._createResource (/var/www/html/myapp/node_modules/generic-pool/lib/generic-pool.js:326:17)
        at Pool.dispense [as _dispense] (/var/www/html/myapp/node_modules/generic-pool/lib/generic-pool.js:314:12)
        at Pool.acquire (/var/www/html/myapp/node_modules/generic-pool/lib/generic-pool.js:392:8)
        at /var/www/html/myapp/node_modules/knex/lib/client.js:281:19
        at Promise._execute (/var/www/html/myapp/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/debuggability.js:299:9)
        at Promise._resolveFromExecutor (/var/www/html/myapp/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:481:18)
        at new Promise (/var/www/html/myapp/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:77:14)
        at Client_Oracle.acquireConnection (/var/www/html/myapp/node_modules/knex/lib/client.js:272:12)

        at /var/www/html/myapp/node_modules/knex/lib/runner.js:200:30
     at Promise._execute (/var/www/html/myapp/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/debuggability.js:299:9)
```

Comment: What is the odbc attribute for?  Knex is heading to use the new 'oracledb' module instead of the obsolete 'oracle' one, see https://github.com/tgriesser/knex/blob/master/test/unit/dialects/oracledb.js for connection example.  Have you installed node-oracledb (or node-oracle, if you really need to use that driver)

Comment: Indeed `node-oracledb` driver and oracledb XE 11.2.0 is currently the only oracle setup that is automatically tested by integration tests.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A combination of knex and OracleDB works fine. Here are packages from package.json:  `"knex": "0.13.0", "oracledb": "1.13.1"`

And the knex call:

```
var conn = knex({
  client: 'oracledb',
  connection: {
    host: config.oracle.host,
    user: config.oracle.user,
    password: config.oracle.password,
    database: config.oracle.database,
  }
});
```

Comment: It's not clear in this answer where the "config.oracle" values are coming from.   Can the author explain where they are set, and give examples?

Comment: well `config` is a plain old javascript object!

`
    var config = {
      oracle: {
        host: '127.0.0.1',
    ...
  }
}
`

Answer (score 3):

In case someone needs to pass a connection string. Please note however, the details inside the connection string will need to match your own environment.

```
const oracledb = require("oracledb");
oracledb.initOracleClient({ libDir: "C:\\oracle\\instantclient_12_1" });

const knex = require("knex")({
    client: "oracledb",
    connection: {
        user: "YOUR_USER",
        password: "YOUR_PASSWORD",
        connectString: "(DESCRIPTION=(CONNECT_TIMEOUT=10)(RETRY_COUNT=3)(SOURCE_ROUTE=yes)(ADDRESS_LIST=(LOAD_BALANCE=on)(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=your2.domain.com)(PORT=11529))(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=your2.domain.com)(PORT=11529)))(ADDRESS_LIST=(FAILOVER=on)(LOAD_BALANCE=off)(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=your3.domain.com)(port=1521))(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=your4.domain.com)(port=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=YOUR_SERVICE.your5.domain.com)))",
        requestTimeout: 100
    },
    fetchAsString: ["number", "clob"]
});

knex.select().from("TABLE1").asCallback(function(err, rows){
    if(err)
        console.log(err);
    else
        console.table(rows);
});
```

Comment: You can also use an 'Easy Connect' string, or a connect descriptor from a tnsnames.ora file. (node-oracledb documentation is [here](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#connectionstrings)).  If you are using 19c client libraries, then the technical article [Oracle
Database 19c Easy Connect Plus Configurable Database Connection Syntax](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#connectionstrings) has some useful info about the latest improvements to the Easy Connect syntax.

Comment: oracledb.initOracleClient this stuff just saved my life)))